# Bootstrap Background Image Change to Video

Tags: html, css, video, background

Following CSS Code snippet is the Problem:

```
.masthead {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 35rem;
  padding: 15rem 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 75%, 
  #000000 100%), url("/assets/img/header_flow.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

I would like to change the Image (GIF at the moment) to an mp4 but it doesn't show up in any browser except Safari..?! because from somewhere it gets the given Attribute of IMG so...

What's the Trick to change this? I know there is another way to do it as (<)video(>) block in HTML but I don't want to write the whole Website frame new because of one little line of Code.. o.O

**Edit:**

I Solved it in HTML like

```
<header class="masthead">
            <div class="video-bg">
                <video muted autoplay loop source src="/assets/vid/video.webm" type="video/webm"></video> 
            </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="container d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
                        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
                            <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Title</h1>
                            <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">Subtitle</h2>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" href="#contactus">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </header>
```

This is not satisfactory to me. With Bootstrap it should be possible to change this in CSS otherwise the option to link bg-files in CSS is pretty useless.

Thx for answering @all even if it doesn't give me the solution I search for :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't put a MP4 file for a background tag in CSS. You have to create a div with the video in src.

Here's an exemple:

HTML:

```html
<video autoplay muted loop src="path/to/video.mp4"></video>

<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
video {
    position: fixed /* or absolute, depend on what you want to do */
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%
    min-height: 100%
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    /* And do whatever you want to do with your content */
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Comment: Yes i know this way as i mentioned in the Question.. but this is not what I want! So means in Bootstrap is no way to solve this without writing the whole thing new.. Wow I'm so glad I use Bootstrap.. -.-

Comment: Now I have written the Html new but the WebM files don't show up in any mobile browser... so this solution also sucks

Comment: Maybe it's because of the file extension but I don't think so, mobiles are supposed to be able to read WebM files.